# Drupal how to send a mail

Tags: email, drupal-7

I'm trying to send custom mail to users, in a module I create these two methods :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function ga_planning_theme() {
  return array(
     'ga_planning_mail_status_change' => array(
     'template' => 'templates/ga_planning_mail_status_change',
     'variables' => array(),
  )
);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_mail().
 */
function ga_planning_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  switch ($key) {
    case 'status_change_mail':
      $message['subject'] = t('Changement de statut');
      $message['body'][] = theme('ga_planning_theme', $params);
      break;
  }
}
```

And I try to send the mail with drupal_mail :

```
drupal_mail('ga_planning', 'ga_planning_mail_status_change', "myadress@mail.com", NULL, $params, variable_get('site_mail'), TRUE);
```

But the mail is not sending, it send a mail to the webmaster mail with the default template and with this subject :

```
DEBUG -  FROM MyWebsite.com
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,please make sure you can send emails and second:
You need to define your **$params** array. For example:

```
$params['test'] = 'ok';
```

And also, try to declare the headers:

```
$message['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed';
$message['subject'] = t('Changement de statut');
$message['body'][] = theme('ga_planning_theme', $params);
```